# Redirect 301 & RewriteCond Collision

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have in my .htaccess file the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /index.asp     http://www.website.com/index.php
Redirect 301 /contact.asp   http://www.website.com/contact.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})$ /$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 error.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) seofile.php?word=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Now,
for some reason, when I entry to contact.asp I'm getting

```
http://www.website.com/seofile.php?word=/contact.asp
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using rewriterule instead of Redirect (I think rewrite rules are applied before redirect rules). So something like:

```
RewriteRule ^index.asp   /             [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^contact.asp /contact.php  [R=301,L]
```

PS. the first rule can be removed, as you already rewrite every index.xxx file.

Answer (score 0):

Advice: try to separate things that don't belong to RewriteRules.

Try this code and please tell me if it works:

```
ErrorDocument 404 error.php

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(index|contact)\.asp $1.php [QSA,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) seofile.php?word=%{REQUEST_URI}
```